# Reading BLE advertisements on Central Role with Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I want to read advertisement packets from BLE peripherals as they contain some information that don't necessarily come at scan response packets.

Is there a way to get information from advertisement of BLE peripherals with Qt (5.5)? I'm not talking about discovering services using QLowEnergyController::discoverServices() which (probably) uses scan response procedure.
Can GAP be reached this deep with Qt?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't for now, it's on the roadmap but there is no ETA :

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46008

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31674

Comment: You can give links as answer but better to include essential parts of answer here..!!